# pegar url atual de uma rede em java

Tags: java

Preciso de alguma maneira de pegar as url's acessadas em uma rede de computadores, ja vi bastante coisa, achei um codigo que usa `socket` mas é de um `host` somente, mas nao pode ser de um `host` individual, quero de toda a rede, alguma classe ou um exemplo de como se faz isso

ps:nao é um servidor `servlet`

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem, mas isso pega todos os hosts de uma lan

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet){
   int timeout=1000;
   for (int i=1;i<254;i++){
       String host=subnet + "." + i;
       if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
           System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
       }
   }
}

//call
checkHosts("192.168.0");
```